# Specifying date range in a request in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some info about trade goods, kinda logistics. It has a column called 'arriving_date', which contains the arrival dates in a format like this "30.06.2019".

Now I need to enter a request which displays only the goods which have not arrived yet, in other words which arrival date is > 30.06.2019. So I'm entering my request

```
SELECT *
FROM traffic
WHERE arriving_date > '30.06.2019'
```

But this request shows me just blank field. And I think I've already guessed why. Apparently it can't compare numbers in a format like that. But I'm not sure how should I make it compare dates then. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Arriving_date should be of type date or datetime and not string. Then you could compare it with WHERE arriving_date > '2019-06-30'

Comment: Try converting arriving_date to datetime format using CONVERT() function and compare it or both fields must in date format in order to compare date

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that arriving_date is just a string (and not an actual date)

```
SELECT *
  FROM traffic
 WHERE str_to_date(arriving_date, '%d.%m.%Y') > now()
    OR arriving_date is null;
```

This will convert the arriving_date string into a date and compare it to the current date and time.

I also added  a check for arriving_date being null (ie not set) in case it's set upon arrival.

Note that using a function on the value from a column makes all queries run full table scan. There is no way around that since your date format is as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for help!

I manage to solve my problem this way:
1. I changed arriving_date data type to 'date' (it was integer)
2. I rewrote dates from format 'dd.mm.yyyy' to 'yyyy-mm-dd', not sure if it matters.
3. final request looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM traffic
WHERE arriving_date > NOW()
```

It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the arriving_date column is a porper date data type try convert the date string in a proper date

```
    SELECT *
    FROM traffic
    WHERE arriving_date > str_to_date('30.06.2019', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

or if both date